# UE5 lumen lighting on Mac

Tags: lighting, unreal-engine5

I own an m1 Mac with Apple's in house chip. I'm also a beginner in Unreal Engine 5. I was following some very beginner tutorials on lighting and lumen. However, lumen doesn't seem to work for me. After setting the global illumination method to lumen, nothing seems to happen or change. Is there a fix for this? Or is it just the fact that I'm using a Mac and lumen isn't supported on it?

Answer (score 1):

The [recommended system specs](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/ContentAndSamples/ValleyOfTheAncient/#:%7E:text=%20Recommended%20System%20Specs%20%201%2012-core%20CPU,AMD%20Radeon%205700%20XT%20or%20higher%20More%20) are
GeForce RTX 2080 / AMD Radeon 5700 XT or higher

Answer (score 1):

I'm on a 14" M1 Macbook Pro and lumen works great.  This is a completely dynamic scene with no baked lighting with lumen dynamic global illumination.  This scene is a red cube in a white room with a single point light.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using parallels once. Check on windows10 arm

Answer (score 0):

Unreal Engine 5.2 Preview 1 added support for Apple Silicon natively, Lumen is included in the build and is enabled by default on new levels.

The following video has been recorded on a MacBook Pro M1 Max on UE 5.2 Preview, it's the default 3rd-person starter level, with the blue cubes updated to have an emissive material and the default directional light set to 0.1. You can observe the emissive cubes bouncing around the level updating the emitted light in real time.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9GhC.jpg